# How to make Objects follow a path (illustrator) (like on the las vegas sign)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Does anyone know how to get objects to follow a path in illustrator symmetrically? For example (and what I am trying to emulate), the Welcome to Las Vegas Sign.

[image]

I figured out the basics of the blend tool and how to duplicate my "lights" to have them follow a path, but I can never get them to go all the way around, nor can I get them to look symmetric.

Comment: Side note, but please sort out your character spacing in "LAS  V E G A S"!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Pattern brush.

- Draw 1 light and create a rectangle around it with no fill and no
  stroke. Move the rectangle **behind** the light artwork.

[image: bulb]

- Drag all that to the Symbols Panel to create a symbol of it. (This
  step just makes editing the light easier later, and is not
  mandatory. To edit the light later, just double-click the Symbol in
  the Symbol Panel.).
- Now that the light is a symbol... drag it from the artboard to the
  Brush Panel and choose Pattern Brush...

[image: brush]

- Now just draw a path and click the brush in the Brush Panel.

[image: Brush]

- You may need to double-click the brush in the Brush Panel and adjust
  some settings....

[image: flip and aprox]

Be aware, this brush is not set up with corner artwork. For this reason any sharp corners will not have lights on them, You'll want to use rounded corners to get the light pattern to appear. A brush **with** corners can be configured. However, creating corner artwork can be a very time-consuming and detailed processes and is not as easily described in a single post. If you need corners, I'd suggest a Google search for "Illustrator Pattern brush Corners tutorial". You'll find much more information than I can provide here regarding corners.

Additionally....

If you set the Colorization method to Hue Shift and then designate the color of your bulb as the Key Color....

[image: shift]

You can then change the color of the lights by simply changing the color of the stroke on your path.....

[image: red]

Comment: Amazing !!!!!! :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It was very helpful.
Lisette

Answer (score 3):

What you really need is a pattern brush. There are options for how the objects are distributed around the path, whether they are true to the measurements or scaled to fit.

You can read about it in [Adobe's Help file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-64faa.html) or there are plenty of good tutorials available:

- [VectorTuts](http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/a-comprehensive-guide-illustrators-paintbrush-tool-and-brush-panel/)
- [Veerle's Blog](http://veerle-v2.duoh.com/blog/comments/seamless_illustrator_pattern_brushes_with_outer_corner_tiles/)
- [GoMedia video](http://vimeo.com/827022)