# Wrapping Shapes to match other shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I have this shape here:
[image]

And I want to get this shape to follow the the curves of the other shape, Something like this:
[image]

But I want it to continue to follow the curves. Ive tried warping, enveloping and free transform, nothing is getting what I want. Im using illustrator and have to keep it in a vector format. Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get a somewhat decent effect by using a pattern brush and the width tool.

1. Draw a unit cell, and draw a no-fill-no-stroke rectangle around it: [image]
2. Select all of this and drag it into the Brushes palette. Choose `Pattern Brush` in the popup that appears: [image]
3. In the popup that appears after that, choose `OK`. [image]
4. Draw your stroke. [image]
5. Apply the Pattern Brush to the stroke. [image]
6. Then, using the Width tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>), adjust the width of the stroke to mimic your desired shape. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom brush to [rotate and bend along curved path](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12916/rotate-and-blend-along-a-curved-path), but to get the narrowing effect near the arms of the 'Z' shape, you will likely need to do some warping. Try [embedding](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/749862?tstart=0) an Illustrator layer in Photoshop.