# Scattered Pixel Effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixelation, pixel-art

I'm trying to learn how to create a scattered pixel effect in Photoshop. I know how to create pixelated graphics. But i'd like to know how to create an effect where the pixels are scattered. Similar to this photo.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the result to be a bitmap, vector paths, or would either be ok? There's quite a few ways to automate something like this.

Comment: vector or psd is fine no bitmaps

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve something similar, try the following:

<sup>*Click the screenshots for full resolution*</sup>

#### Create a new document with relatively small dimensions.

[image: New Document dialog]

#### Select the Pen tool, change the size to 1px

[image: pen tool]

#### Edit the Brush settings (Window → Brush) for Spacing

*I set Spacing at 750%*

[image: Brush settings]

#### Edit the Brush settings for Scattering

*I set Scatter at 1000% and Count Jitter at 100%.*

[image: Brush settings]

#### Edit the Color Dynamics for the Brush settings

*This is a "play around with the settings and see what works" step. I changed the saturation and brightness to 92% and 61% respectively.*

[image: Brush settings]

#### With the color you want the pixels to be selected, scribble around the document.

*The result will be randomly scattered pixels.*

[image: Scribble]

#### Enlarge the image using Nearest Neighbor enlargement to preserve the hard edges.

[image: Finis]

Answer (score 2):

I would build a segment by hand and then [apply it as a pattern](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-patterns.html).

You could also build the segment in Illustrator and [create a pattern brush](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/how-to-make-objects-follow-a-path-illustrator-like-on-the-las-vegas-sign) with it.