# How to make a Pattern brush that doesn't distort the pattern shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, patterns, brush

we have a LASER-CUT machine, and we need to build a template for strass & Diamond.
I use Adobe Illustrator CS6, and I've tried to let the object follow the path of template using `Pattern Brush`.

But it seems useless to me, because I want:

- No Convergency in any place of path.
- No Distortion in the red circles.
- Fixed Spacing between each shape in Pattern, that I can change it when needed.
- A way that let me to edit the shape (like editing the radius of Red-Circles) and that change would be applied automatically to all patterns that uses this shape.

This image shows the issue and a mockup of the solution I want:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Objects follow a path (illustrator) (like on the las vegas sign)](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/how-to-make-objects-follow-a-path-illustrator-like-on-the-las-vegas-sign)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a scatter brush. This should eliminate the distortion problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank u Mr. @Luciano , but there are some edit to match my need:
(Rotation ---> 90 + Fixed, Spacing ----> 13, Size ----> 10) ... But your answer is exactly what I need ... Anyway, I still have some problem:

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it solves your question.

Comment: Anyway, I still have some problem: this 
[link](https://s10.postimg.org/anzsl0j2h/result.png)
 has the result :(

Comment: Offset each path separately.

Answer (score 2):

While @Luciano answers how you get the pattern stamped along your path he does not answer how to make the new patterns follow the sub-paths in the way you want. First you need to think in terms of multiple paths offset with **Object → Path → Offset Path...**. Then remove the end caps.

**TIP**: It might bve a good idea to make a slightly longer path than intended so the end aligns as you like.

**TIP 2**: You can use the Pen tool to reverse a path if you end up with differently aligned paths.

[image]

**Image 1**: Individual tracks made with offset.

Then use a pattern brush or a dashed stroke to make a patter on each individual path. This ensures you get a uniform pattern. Unfortunately, and this is why I was hesitant to share there is no foolproof way of doing these things for all corner cases. IN some cases you will end up needing to do some spring dynamic contraction and even then its not what you like unless you do it manually.

[image]

**Image 1**: Multiple uniformly distributed objects along path.

**PS**: Illustrator may in fact be the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thank you mr. @joojaa ... I think it will more difficult to do a the sub path using offset because we have to do a lot of designs that have the same problem, and I have no idea about other programs. I prefer to do scatter brush. Then fux the converge manually. Do u think a way that check an area of selection to have one shape and remove others of above. I mean a way of scripting or action ... if it's possible it will save my time of manual fixing

Comment: @AbdulkaderKhateeb Yes it can be done. Illustrator isn't really a CAD though.

Comment: Mmmm .. that is the truth ... I don't know how to thank you Mr. @joojaa